# Slow page loading

Tags: support

On SO when I view a post the page is loading really slow. I've checked the requests with FireBug and got this:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5525261/ivc/8de0

with loading time 15 seconds and "204 No Content"
It's quite annoying.

I've just found I have the same problem here at the meta website. The problem code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/posts/85765/ivc/1b21"></script>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The page loads quickly but I can not vote or comment till the script has been loaded. Happens both at home and work & Linux & Windows , so I think that rules firewalls out ( Unless India has a china like firewall :-P ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce this.

Are you behind a proxy or firewall that would interfere with 204 no content being returned? It's a valid HTTP status code.